# gnu-make: Using individual files in a folder as dependencies and run rule on all filenames in folder

Tags: gnu-make

Suppose I have a file structure as follows:

```
code
├── configure
├── configure.in
├── Demo
│   ├── experiments
│   │   ├── 1.txt
│   │   ├── 2.txt
│   │   ├── 3.txt
│   │   ├── 4.txt
│   │   ├── 5.txt
│   │   └── 6.txt
|   |___test.cpp
```

I am trying to create a rule that uses each one of the files in txt and creates the following files:

1.test
2.test
3.test
4.test
5.test

If I had the rule:

```
%.test: %.txt 
        do something
```

How do I run it on every file in experiments eg:

```
make *.test
```

and then run them individually eg:

```
.\*.test?
```

I really need help with this as I have thousands of files to process in this way.

Comment: "each one of the files in txt". There is not directory called `txt`. Do you mean `experiments`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(wildcard)`:

```
TEST_SOURCES = $(wildcard *.txt)
TEST_OUTPUT = $(patsubst %.txt,%.test,${TEST_SOURCES})

all: ${TEST_OUTPUT}
```